# htaccess 301 redirect from directory to file

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, vbulletin

I have inherited a site (a [vbulletin](https://www.vbulletin.com/) forum) and migrated it from another hosting to mine, by copying everything with `scp` command. The root directory had the following `.htaccess`

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/forums\/content\/" [R=301,L]
```

I don't know how this was supposed to work, but it worked, regardless of the fact that the `/forums/content/` folder did NOT exist. However, once moved to my hosting, it's stopped working, yielding a 404 error.
Since the `/forums/content.php` file exists instead, I've edited the `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/forums\/content.php" [R=301,L]
```

Now it's working, with a glitch: my browser (and every other forum user browser) is caching the previous 301 redirect, so I can reach and use the forum only if I clear the browser cache (once), or if I enter the `content.php` URL by hand (every time).

I've tried the workaround to add a redirect from `/forums/content/` to `/forums/content.php`, by adding a `RewriteRule` to `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/forums/content/$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/forums\/content.php" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/forums\/content.php" [R=301,L]
```

However it seems that rule is ignored, because the browser still gets a 404 error on the `/forums/content/` directory and it does not redirect to `content.php`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There will be no leading `/` to match in the url when in a .htaccess file. Try `^forums/`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As meuh mentioned in comments, when mod_rewrite is used in per-directory `.htaccess` files, there is no leading slash prefix on the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. The directory-prefix (which always *ends in a slash*) is first removed.

However, your directives are also in the wrong order and could be tidied. The `RewriteCond` directive applies to the single `RewriteRule` that follows. You've inserted the `RewriteRule` between these directives, so you've effectively changed the logic. But these two `RewriteRule` directives could be easily combined and that `RewriteCond` directive looks superfluous.

Unless you specifically need the `RewriteOptions` directive, I would remove it. This might have been required on the previous host.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(forums/content/)?$ http://example.com/forums/content.php [R=301,L]
```

The *pattern* `^(forums/content/)?$` matches either `/forums/content/` or simply `/`, which is what the original `RewriteRule` was matching.

I've removed the `RewriteCond` directive that checked against `HTTP_HOST`. I assume it was supposed to have matched *something* (ie. not nothing). However, it simply matched *anything* which would *always* be true, which seems to be a bit pointless.

No need for all the backslash escaping in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. This is an ordinary string, not a regex. (That sort of unnecessary escaping is typical of cPanel.)

**UPDATE:** You'll need to ensure that MultiViews is not enabled. This can be disabled with the `Options` directive near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

If you have existing `Options` directives then this can be combined, for example:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
```

Since `/forums` is a physical directory, if MultiViews is enabled then it can result in mod_negotiation making an internal request for `content.php` (or even something else, like `content.html` if it exists) before mod_rewrite is able to trigger the redirect.

Comment: A few days ago I accepted this answer, but I don't remember if I tried the solution before accepting: maybe I accepted it just because it seemed logic. However the solution is now in place, but I realize it is not working, because `/forums/content/` still yelds a 404.

Comment: Presumably you are not being redirected to `/forums/content.php`? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? "I don't know how this was supposed to work" - from your original statement, if "/forums/content/" didn't exist as a physical directory then there must have been other directives in `.htaccess` that helped route the request (ie. a _front controller_)?

Comment: Maybe there were other directives outside of `.htaccess`. My current `.htaccess` contains only the two lines you suggested, and the hosting Apache instance is configured with a fairly plain VirtualHost with no redirects. BTW your solution DOES work when the browser opens `/`, but not when the browser opens `/forums/content/`

Comment: It sounds like you might have MultiViews enabled. Try disabling it with `Options -MultiViews` near the top of your `.htaccess` file. (If you have an existing `Options` directive then you can combine it.) If MultiViews is enabled then it can result in mod_negotiation making an internal request for `content.php` (or something else) _before_ mod_rewrite is able to trigger the redirect.

Comment: Bingo! It works! Thanks a lot. If you edit your answer with the `Options -MultiViews` thing, I'll be glad to accept it again.